# Button with border bottom and border radius not expected results

Tags: css

Here's what i want to accomplish:

[image]

As you can see, there's a small border at the bottom, i've tried to add `border-bottom: 1px solid #c1ad6f` but it results to:

[image]

Border is not fully filled cause of radius.

```css
.btn {
  background: #d5c289;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #c1ad6f;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#form" role="button">Enroll</a>
```

Comment: please share your code...

Comment: I kinda published my single line code already, it's all the same and simple.

Comment: Listen to me very carefully, the issue with the current CSS is hardly seen.

Comment: @AlexanderKim, you could increase border-bottom. like this: `border-bottom: 5px solid #c1ad6f;`.  I made this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bektkdnz/ but increased padding so it was easier to see.

Comment: @user2796515, thanks, i've bumped to `6px` so everyone could clearly see :D

Comment: @AlexanderKim.  I added as an answer if this was useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider `box-shadow` instead of border to achieve this in a better way:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #d5c289;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 0 0 #c1ad6f inset;
  animation: anime 2s infinite linear alternate;
}
.border {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #c1ad6f;
  animation: anime-alt 2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@keyframes anime {
  from {box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #c1ad6f inset;}
  to {box-shadow: 0 -30px 0 0 #c1ad6f inset;}}
@keyframes anime-alt {
  from {border-bottom: 1px solid #c1ad6f;}
  to {border-bottom: 30px solid #c1ad6f;}}
```

```html
<div class="box shadow">
  Good one with box-shadow
</div>

<div class="box border">
  Not good with border
</div>
```

Comment: I suspected, that i've used not the right tool for that, could you explain why with borders it's getting stripped? It's eating border when the radius starts.

Comment: @AlexanderKim i would say this is how border works :) By they way all depend on their width and the border-radius as you may obtain want you want considering some values

Comment: @AlexanderKim I updated with some animation so you can see the result better ;)

Comment: Thanks. now i see that.

Answer (score 0):

> This is simple trick to make border rounded using box-shadow. it will
>   exactly giving the output what you want.

```css
.btn-bordered {
    background: #17aa56;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px #119e4d;
    padding: 25px 60px 25px 90px;
}
.btn-block {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 25px 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    text-transform: Capitialize;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-bordered btn-block" type="button">Bottom Rounded Button</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

@AlexanderKim, you could increase border-bottom. like this: border-bottom: 5px solid #c1ad6f;. I made this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/bektkdnz but increased padding so it was easier to see